# How to store different types of methods in a dictionary from different classes in C#

Tags: c#

I'm building a windows app to be able to read a txt file that contains a lot of markup that explains what kind of information is provided. The markup used looks like "#FLAG xxx" where xxx is the information that is retrieved. The information is handled differently depending on the markup used and therefore I need different methods to extract it.

In my program I use a Dictionary to store all possible variations of markup that can be in the file can contain, and then I read every row in the file and compare if there is a hit in the Dictionary. As it is now, I hardcode what method to call but feel it must be a stupid way to solve this. I load everything contained in the Dictionaryn from another class (Settings), which means I can not access the methods I put in my first class (Form1).

I know I'm doing a lot of mistakes here, but I'm really new to C# and can't do a better solution myself. How would a better practise be to solve this problem. I don't want to write lots of if-statements if I don't need to.

The code below is a downward version of what I have written. Othervise it will be to messy to read. And yes, I removed the Excel-export part but hopefylly you can see what I'm trying to do anyway.

Forms1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace MarkupReader
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "File (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        ofd.Title = "Open file";
        ofd.Multiselect = false;

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName), Encoding.GetEncoding(437));
            ExportFile(readFile);
            readFile.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void ExportFile(StreamReader readFile)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, int, string>> markup = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, int, string>>();

        readFile.DiscardBufferedData();
        readFile.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

        Settings settings = new Settings();
        settings.SetMarkup(markup);

        string fileMarkup = "";
        string fileMarkupValues = "";
        string line = "";

        while (line != null)
        {
            line = readFile.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                //Get markup
                fileMarkup = line.Trim().Split(' ').First();
                fileMarkupValues = line.Replace(fileMarkup, "");

                if (markup.ContainsKey(fileMarkup))
                {
                    /* markupItemX = X is content
                     * Item1 = User flag
                     * Item2 = Export to worksheet number
                     * Item3 = Extract method to call
                     * Item4 = 
                     */

                    //Export to excel sheet 1
                    if (markup[fileMarkup].Item2 == 1)
                    {
                        if (markup[fileMarkup].Item3 == "extractDataOne") ExtractMethodOne(fileMarkupValues);
                        if (markup[fileMarkup].Item3 == "extractDataTwo") ExtractMethodTwo(fileMarkupValues);
                        if (markup[fileMarkup].Item3 == "extractDataThree") ExtractMethodThree(fileMarkupValues);
                        if (markup[fileMarkup].Item3 == "extractDataFour") ExtractMethodFour(fileMarkupValues);
                        if (markup[fileMarkup].Item3 == "extractDataFive") ExtractMethodFive(fileMarkupValues);
                    }
                    //Export to excel sheet 2
                    if (markup[fileMarkup].Item2 == 2)
                    {
                        if (markup[fileMarkup].Item3 == "extractDataOne") ExtractMethodOne(fileMarkupValues);
                        if (markup[fileMarkup].Item3 == "extractDataTwo") ExtractMethodTwo(fileMarkupValues);
                        if (markup[fileMarkup].Item3 == "extractDataThree") ExtractMethodThree(fileMarkupValues);
                        if (markup[fileMarkup].Item3 == "extractDataFour") ExtractMethodFour(fileMarkupValues);
                        if (markup[fileMarkup].Item3 == "extractDataFive") ExtractMethodFive(fileMarkupValues);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ExtractMethodOne(string markupData)
    {
        //Extract stuff and write to Excel
    }

    public void ExtractMethodTwo(string markupData)
    {
        //Extract stuff and write to Excel
    }

    public void ExtractMethodThree(string markupData)
    {
        //Extract stuff and write to Excel
    }

    public void ExtractMethodFour(string markupData)
    {
        //Extract stuff and write to Excel
    }

    public void ExtractMethodFive(string markupData)
    {
        //Extract stuff and write to Excel
    }

}
}
```

Setting.cs (it really contains alot more, this is just a example)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MarkupReader
{
class Settings
{
    public void SetMarkup(Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, int, string>> markup)
    {
        int workSheet = 1;
        markup.Add("#FLAG", new Tuple<string, int, string>("User flag", workSheet, "extractDataOne"));
        markup.Add("#FORMAT", new Tuple<string, int, string>("User format", workSheet, "extractDataOne"));
        markup.Add("#TYPE", new Tuple<string, int, string>("User type", workSheet, "extractDataOne"));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the signature of your `ExtractX` methods (void with one string param), you can do something like this:

```
// Static field or whatever you want
Dictionary<string, Action<string>> methods = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>()
{
    { "extractDataOne", ExtractMethodOne },
    { "extractDataTwo", ExtractMethodTwo },
    { "extractDataThree", ExtractMethodThree },
    { "extractDataFour", ExtractMethodFour },
    { "extractDataFive", ExtractMethodFive },
};

// And then use it like this
methods[markup[fileMarkup].Item3].Invoke(fileMarkupValues);
```

Although I don't understand how you're gonna differienciate between sheet 1 and 2 since you use the same methods for both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

extract from a current project of mine

```
private static Dictionary<string, Func<DataObj, string>> s_FormulaMap =
new Dictionary<string, Func<DataObj>, string>> {
    { "home", d=>GetHome(d) },
    { "shell", d=>MakeupShell(d) },
    { "user", d=>d.Get("User") }
};
```

thss maps literals to Func's. The funcs take a DataObj and return a string.
Then do

```
 var func = s_FormulaMap[keyWord];
            val = func(de);
```